# Best way to mapply with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table and 2 vectors:

```
    > dt = data.table(a = c('hi', 'ok', 'no', 'ok', 'no', 'www', 'whatever'))
> dt
          a
1:       hi
2:       ok
3:       no
4:       ok
5:       no
6:      www
7: whatever
v1 = c('hi', 'no')
v2 = c('HI', 'NO')
> v1
[1] "hi" "no"
> v2
[1] "HI" "NO"
```

I want to replace the values found from v1 in dt to those of v2. If I find 'hi' I will replace by 'HI' and if I find 'no' I replace by 'NO'.

The easiest way I found was to do:

```
invisible(mapply(function(x, y) `[`(dt, grepl(x, a), a := y), x = v1, y = v2))
> dt
          a
1:       HI
2:       ok
3:       NO
4:       ok
5:       NO
6:      www
7: whatever
```

Is there a better way or even a way to do it using mapply in the j argument of data.table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be better with a join here

```
dt[data.table(v1, v2), a:= v2, on = .(a = v1)]
```

-output

```
dt
          a
1:       HI
2:       ok
3:       NO
4:       ok
5:       NO
6:      www
7: whatever
```

Comment: @daniellga is there any chance for partial matches

Comment: @akrun that's like r2evans said. I will modify my question so it has more cases in dt.

Comment: I modified dt in the question, could you modify your answer with it so I give you the correct one?

Comment: if I need to use a grepl to get partial matches instead of a perfect match between v1 and dt, how could I do it?

Comment: @daniellga then you may need `fuzzyjoin` i.e. `regex_left_join(dt, data.table(a = v1, v2), by = 'a')`